# How to activate unstable feature restricted_std in rust-analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I'm trying to compile for esp32c6 (`riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf`). Actually, `cargo build` runs, but when I save the file rust-analyzer checks it and complains:

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'restricted_std'
   --> /home/lz/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/test/src/formatters/json.rs:225:55
    |
225 |     fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> ::std::fmt::Result {
    |                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: add `#![feature(restricted_std)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

As you see, it's complaining about a feature in the std lib, which is strange. I added `#![feature(restricted_std)]` to main.rs but the error is in the standard library where I cannot add this feature.

I also tried

```yaml
{
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.cfgs": {
        "build-std": ["core", "std", "alloc", "panic_abort"],
        "restricted_std": true
    },
    "rust-analyzer.check.allTargets": false,
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.target": "riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf"
}
```

and other variations without success. Also tried

```toml
[unstable]
features = ["restricted_std"]
```

in `rust-analyzer.toml`.

Also

```sh
~/project1$ rustup toolchain install riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf
error: invalid toolchain name: 'riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf'
```

Comment: It seems rust-analyzer is using a wrong copy of libstd.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you mean the x86 version? I tried changing the default toolchain but I couldn't

Comment: I'd suggest to consider also [raising an issue ticket](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/new/choose) if you think this is a bug. If you do, please comment here with a link to your issue ticket.